# SP13 with IP13 forms and no IP13

Tags: infopath-2013

Are there workarounds for manipulating InfoPath forms now that IP13 has been deprecated? Caveats: I cannot use SPD (limited [EDIT] END-user [for lack of a better term] SP deployment) and I now have a machine with MS Office 2016 (IP no longer offered as a stand-alone program). I have several IP forms that were created when I had a Office 2013 machine that need updating, etc. Is my only option to delete the IP forms and just use OOTB solutions? Thank you in advance for any help/info/answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not continue using IP? It's still available and even supported on Windows 10.

"Although Microsoft is not continuing development of InfoPath products, it will continue support of these products until 2023. For more information, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/"

Microsoft is still adding documentation updates about InfoPath in DOCs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/infopath/infopath-forms-services

IP forms with code are not supported in SharePoint Online, and will generally not work with the Modern UI.

"Deprecated" has at least three definitions!

- No longer supported, can't use, don't bother trying.
- Please don't use in new projects, may be obsoleted in the future.
- Still works just fine, we may be thinking about another option or limiting it in some way, but we won't be upgrading it any more (except maybe for security fixes).

Download:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48734

Comment: Understood and thank you for your reply. However, the machine I have now has MS Office 2016 installed which unfortunately does not have InfoPath available. When I asked my IT department [government] what happened to InfoPath and why I needed it, I was informed that MS had deprecated the program in MSO2016 and that they could not install IP2013 to an MSO2016 machine. So... I’m left with no means to manipulate/update the IP forms I created on SP2013 when I had the machine with MSO2013 installed. I’m curious if there are workarounds, i.e., another method to manipulate the current IP forms.

Comment: Looks like I can request a reinstall. But I’m open to other solutions if possible. Thx. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_infopath_bloggers/2016/03/01/infopath-is-not-included-in-office-2016/

Comment: I too am running Office 2016 ProPlus, AND also on the same PC, SharePoint Designer 2013 and InfoPath 2013 (and InfoPath 2010). Which Office edition do you have? Have you tried installing it from the link in my answer?

Comment: So far, I've not seen a third party direct replacement for IP. You could hand edit the XML files!  :-(